# Update Enum Options using Laravel Migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration

If the enums are modified in the enums.php file, how would I change the migration?

I have my migration file like the following-

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('increase_pond_height', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->float('height', 8, 2);
            $table->enum('purpose', Config::get('enums.increase_pond_height_purposes'));
            $table->string('comments', 500)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I have the enum.php in Config like the following-

```
<?php

return [
    'increase_pond_height_purposes' => ['innoculum', 'harvest', 'media_addition']
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : you can't

Each time you edit your `enum.php` config file **Manually** you must add a new migration to alter your `increase_pond_height` table